# How does sequence and changing state not matter in functional programming languages vs in OOP?

Tags: oop, functional-programming

I read how imperative languages depend on a certain sequence to do things, which I can see, but cannot the same be said for functional programming as well that we need to follow a certain sequence of commands or procedures to get to a certain result, for example in some sort of math computation? Also, I read how imperative languages, OOP specifically, will be changing the state of the program, in that case would not every certain calculation or computation be changing the state of the program indirectly in functional programming as well?

Comment: You need to provide a minimal code to reproduce the problem. See more details on how to post a question at this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: If we assume a lazy setting evaluation order mainly depends on data dependencies. Expressions are only evaluated when needed. The absence of side effects make these dependencies quite explicit. Their might be compiler optimizations for certain types/operations due to mathematical laws/substitutions though. If we narrow the meaning of state to data that changes during runtime, then there is no state in purely functional PLs. What you have instead is name bindings with the same name in different function scopes. State is held in the function call stack.